# Not able to retrieve all rows from resultset

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

PFB the code I used:

```
       ResultSet rs1_1 = stmt1_1.executeQuery("select dfd.document_id,dfd.country_id,dfi.folder_name from dossier_folder_documents dfd,dossier_folder_info dfi where dfd.fk_dossier_folder_id=dfi.pk_dossier_folder_id and dfd.is_core is null and dfd.action='N' and dfd.fk_dossier_basic_info_id in (select pk_dossier_id from dossier_basic_info where dossier_id= '"+vdlist.get(g)+"') and (dfd.document_id,dfi.folder_name) not in(select dfd.document_id,dfi.folder_name from dossier_folder_documents dfd,dossier_folder_info dfi where dfd.fk_dossier_folder_id=dfi.pk_dossier_folder_id  and dfd.fk_dossier_basic_info_id in (select pk_dossier_id from dossier_basic_info where dossier_id= '"+sdlist.get(g)+"' and data_state='C'))");


        ResultSet rs1_2 = stmt1_2.executeQuery("select dfd.document_id,dfd.country_id,dfi.folder_name from dossier_folder_documents dfd,dossier_folder_info dfi where dfd.fk_dossier_folder_id=dfi.pk_dossier_folder_id and dfd.action='N' and dfd.fk_dossier_basic_info_id in (select pk_dossier_id from dossier_basic_info where dossier_id='"+vdlist.get(g)+"') and (dfd.document_id,dfd.country_id,dfi.folder_name) not in (select dfd.document_id,dfd.country_id,dfi.folder_name from dossier_folder_documents dfd,dossier_folder_info dfi where  dfd.fk_dossier_folder_id=dfi.pk_dossier_folder_id  and dfd.fk_dossier_basic_info_id in (select pk_dossier_id from dossier_basic_info where dossier_id='"+sdlist.get(g)+"' and data_state='C'))");



        ResultSet rs2_1 = stmt2_1.executeQuery("select dfd.document_id,dfd.country_id,dfi.folder_name from dossier_folder_documents dfd,dossier_folder_info dfi where dfd.fk_dossier_folder_id=dfi.pk_dossier_folder_id and dfd.is_core is null and dfd.action='O' and dfd.fk_dossier_basic_info_id in (select pk_dossier_id from dossier_basic_info where dossier_id = '"+vdlist.get(g)+"') and (dfd.document_id,dfi.folder_name) in (select dfd.document_id,dfi.folder_name from dossier_folder_documents dfd,dossier_folder_info dfi where dfd.fk_dossier_folder_id=dfi.pk_dossier_folder_id  and dfd.fk_dossier_basic_info_id in (select pk_dossier_id from dossier_basic_info where dossier_id = '"+sdlist.get(g)+"' and data_state='C'))");



        ResultSet rs2_2 = stmt2_2.executeQuery("select dfd.document_id,dfd.country_id,dfi.folder_name from dossier_folder_documents dfd,dossier_folder_info dfi where dfd.fk_dossier_folder_id=dfi.pk_dossier_folder_id and dfd.action='O' and dfd.fk_dossier_basic_info_id in (select pk_dossier_id from dossier_basic_info where dossier_id='"+vdlist.get(g)+"') and (dfd.document_id,dfd.country_id,dfi.folder_name)  in (select dfd.document_id,dfd.country_id,dfi.folder_name from dossier_folder_documents dfd,dossier_folder_info dfi where  dfd.fk_dossier_folder_id=dfi.pk_dossier_folder_id  and dfd.fk_dossier_basic_info_id in (select pk_dossier_id from dossier_basic_info where dossier_id='"+sdlist.get(g)+"' and data_state='C'))");

        ResultSetMetaData rsmd1 = rs1_1.getMetaData();
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd2 = rs2_1.getMetaData();
        String temp5 = new String();
        for(int f=1;f<=rsmd1.getColumnCount();f++)
            {
                data3+=rsmd1.getColumnName(f)+"/ /";}
                temp4=data3;
                data3="";

                 while(rs1_1.next())
                    {
                        //System.out.println("In here...");
                        num2=g;
                        for(int x=1;x<=rsmd1.getColumnCount();x++)
                            {
                                temp5+=rs1_1.getString(x)+"/ /";    
                            }
                        String data5 = new String();
                        data5=temp5;
                        sublist1.add(data5);
                        //System.out.println("New Null: "+data5);
                        temp5="";
                        //System.out.println(sublist);
                        errvdlist.add(vdlist.get(num2));
                        errsdlist.add(sdlist.get(num2));
                        //System.out.println("Validation Dossier ID for New Corruption: "+vdlist.get(num2));
                        //System.out.println("Submission Dossier ID for New Corruption: "+sdlist.get(num2));

                    }
                while(rs1_2.next())
                {
                    //System.out.println("In here...");
                    num2=g;
                    for(int x=1;x<=rsmd1.getColumnCount();x++)
                        {
                            temp5+=rs1_2.getString(x)+"/ /";    
                        }
                    String data5 = new String();
                    data5=temp5;
                    sublist1.add(data5);
                    //System.out.println("New Not Null: "+data5);
                    temp5="";
                    //System.out.println(sublist);
                    errvdlist.add(vdlist.get(num2));
                    errsdlist.add(sdlist.get(num2));
                    //System.out.println("Validation Dossier ID for New Corruption: "+vdlist.get(num2));
                    //System.out.println("Submission Dossier ID for New Corruption: "+sdlist.get(num2));

                }

                while(rs2_1.next())
                {
                    num2=g;
                    for(int x=1;x<=rsmd2.getColumnCount();x++)
                        {
                            temp6+=rs2_1.getString(x)+"/ /";
                        }
                    //String data6 = new String();
                    data6=temp6;
                    sublist2.add(data6);
                    System.out.println("Old Null: "+data6);
                    temp6="";
                    data6="";
                    //System.out.println(sublist);
                    errvdlist.add(vdlist.get(num2));
                    errsdlist.add(sdlist.get(num2));
                    //System.out.println("Validation Dossier ID for Old Corruption: "+vdlist.get(num2));
                    //System.out.println("Submission Dossier ID for Old Corruption: "+sdlist.get(num2));
                }

                while(rs2_2.next() )
                {
                    num2=g;
                    for(int x=1;x<=rsmd2.getColumnCount();x++)
                        {
                            temp6+=rs2_2.getString(x)+"/ /";
                        }
                    //String data6 = new String();
                    data6=temp6;
                    sublist2.add(data6);
                    System.out.println("Old Not Null: "+data6);
                    temp6="";
                    //System.out.println(sublist);
                    errvdlist.add(vdlist.get(num2));
                    errsdlist.add(sdlist.get(num2));
                    //System.out.println("Validation Dossier ID for Old Corruption: "+vdlist.get(num2));
                    //System.out.println("Submission Dossier ID for Old Corruption: "+sdlist.get(num2));
                }
            }
```

The query specified for resultset `rs2_1` is supposed to return two rows, but it only returns one. All the other queries return multiple rows and the other resultsets work fine. Need help as I can't think of any other reason.

Comment: does the query return multiple entries when run on db explorer? Have you commited after inserting data in database?

Comment: Using multiple ResultSets in sequence like this is usually a bad idea.  I would encapsulate these into separate, testable methods OR I'd rewrite the query to use JOIN and return what I wanted in one network round trip.  There's too much code here; it's hard to read and understand.  The code in the while loops looks like it's been cut & pasted.  That should be a signal that you can and should refactor.

Comment: You are posting too much code with a too vague description of the problem. Please reduce your code to a [mcve], describe your problem in more details, and make sure you include relevant DDL and sample data to reproduce this.

Comment: This was the result of a logical discrepancy. I shall make a note of Mark's suggestion. Thank you all!